# Set with custom compare

Tags: c++, set

In my project I use `std::set` with custom Compare function for maintaining an event queue. It fulfills following criteria:

- event duplication is not allowed
- should maintain the insertion order

(tried `std::vector` first, but that performed poorly because of complicated duplicate removal)

The important code is:

```
template <typename T>
class EventQueue {
public:
  EventQueue() : set_(std::set<DataWrap>()) {}
  void Insert(T elem) {
    set_.insert(DataWrap(elem, set_.size()));
  }

  // ....

private:
  struct DataWrap {
    T data;
    unsigned int order;
    DataWrap(T d, unsigned int o) : data(d), order(o) {}
    bool operator<(const DataWrap& other) const {
      if (data == other.data)
        return false;
      else
        return order < other.order;
    }
  };
  std::set<DataWrap> set_;
};
```

Naturally I want to avoid undefined behaviour. As far as I can see my Compare fulfills the [requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) of *strick weak ordering* (irreflexive, transitive, asymetric)

Can you confirm that this code is well-defined, or am I missing something? Thanks for your time!

Comment: If the size of the vector isn't too large then dupe removal can be a loop over the data and then *not inserting* the duplicate if you find one. That'll be fast enough. Though you'll want something more akin to a circular buffer for fast pop_front behavior.

Comment: This doesn't check for unique elements of `T` at all! The `std::vector` variant would be linear but at least correct. If you don't have `LessThanComparable<T>` available, then you have to try hashing to get better than linear asymptotics.

Comment: @ratchetfreak usually i have 50-100 event in the set and 10-20 duplicate from it. I will investigate further vector based solution!

Comment: @Maikel doesn't checking for `==` of `T` mean it checks for unique elements?

Comment: @Incomputable @pergy `std::set` will check only `log(n)` elements selected by the bisection defined on its comparison operator. This doesn't guarantee uniqueness of elements of `T`, only uniqueness to insertion ids.

Comment: @Maikel, (and pergy)  lets continue discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56350/discussion-on-event-queue)

Comment: It is not transitive. Consider `a(x, 0), b(y, 1), c(x, 3)`. Here `a < b`, `b < c`, but `!(a < c)`.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, you pass the element by copy not by const reference. This might also have some real preformance effects. SO rather do

```
 void Insert(const T&)
```

Also you could use emplace_back to enable inplace construction of the elements in the vector. On the other hand std::find only takes const T& so I would guess, that move semantics do not really buy you anything here.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I changed it to accept `const&`

Answer (score 0):

As it can be concluded from precious comments my design has major flaws:

First, it fails to avoid having duplicates. As @Maikel pointed out

> `std::set` will check only log(n) elements selected by the bisection
>   defined on its comparison operator. This doesn't guarantee uniqueness
>   of elements of `T`, only uniqueness to insertion ids

As an example:

> Let the Event Type `T` be `int`. So this wrapper is something like
>
> ```
> {42,1}, {24,2}, {3,3}, {12, 4} ...
> ```
>
> If we add another `42` into the queue we might do a bisection: Go to
>   the middle, let's check the upper part of set. It will be something
>   like
>
> ```
> {42,1}, {24, 2}, {3,3}, {12,4}, {42,5}
> ```
>
> because `{42,1}` will never get compared with `{42,5}`

It also fails to fulfill *strict weak ordering* requirements. As @vnp pointed out

> It is not transitive. Consider `a(x, 0), b(y, 1), c(x, 3)`.
>
> Here `a < b`, `b < c`, but `!(a < c)`

Many thanks! (if you guys formulate an answer I accept it gladly)

---

As a result I refactored the queue to use `std::vector` as underlying data struct and check for duplicates at insertion time. Optimized for consecutive duplicates as it's more likely in my case.

```
template <typename T>
class EventQueue {
public:
  EventQueue() : v_(std::vector<T>()) {}
  void Insert(const T& elem) {
    if (std::find(v_.rbegin(), v_.rend(), elem) == v_.rend()) {
      v_.push_back(elem);
    }  // else drop
  }

  // ....

private:
  std::vector<T> v_;
};
```

Comment: Hi, for the next question, you should not edit your code after a recommendation. Better create a new answer with the new code. If somebody write an elaborate answer, it will not make any sense anymore once you have changed your code